# Update Currency Rates via shell

Tags: currency-rates

A question that one would expect to find the answer to... But except for cron settings etcetera I can't find it.

Question: "How to import currency rates via shell"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,Can do this by create a `shell php`  and `include Mage.php at first line of code`. Then create an array which is `included the rate in below format`and using `Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->saveRates($rate);` update the currency rate.

See At: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-currency-code-currency-rate/

**CODE & FORMAT:**

```
$rate=array();
$rate[BASE_CURRENCY_CODE][YOUR_CURRENCY_CODE]=YOUR_CURRENCY_RATE_INR;
Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->saveRates($rate);
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$rate=array();
$rate[USD][INR]=62.0924;
$rate[USD][HKD]=7.502;
$rate[USD][USD]=1.00;
Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->saveRates($rate);
```

### Shell Code:

```
require_once 'YOUR_MAGENTODIR/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin');
$currencyModel = Mage::getModel('directory/currency');
$currencies = $currencyModel->getConfigAllowCurrencies();
$defaultCurrencies = $currencyModel->getConfigBaseCurrencies();
$rate=array();
foreach( $currencies as $key => $value ) {
 $rate[$defaultCurrencies[0]][$value]='YourRate';
}
Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->saveRates($rate);
```